# ImageButton color not changing onPressed(), onFocus()

Tags: imagebutton, android, android-drawable

I want to change button colour when pressed, focused and clicked, but I think I must have done something wrong, my code doesn't work. Would someone please advice? Thanks!

This is my `soundbtn.xml` in drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/sound_onpress_mdp" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/sound_onpress_mdp" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sound" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And then I added background to `ImageButton` in layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageSound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/soundbtn"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/sound" />
```

And this is my Java code:

```
private ImageButton btnSound;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);

    btnSound =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSound);
    btnSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundbtn);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove

```
 android:src="@drawable/sound"
```

and

```
 btnSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundbtn);
```

You just need

```
 android:background="@drawable/soundbtn"
```

because it calls the items like 'pressed' or 'focused' which has the target drawables.